Write a DataFrame "array of integer" column to MySQL without using JSON
I have a dataframe df, one of its column is an array of integers. When I did df.info(), the column is object type, I believe this is because DataFrame Dtypes has object as a very generic data type that can mean many things.
I use df.to_sql() to write the dataframe to mysql. I realized that the mysql column is json type, {100, 200, 300, 400}. It is not efficient for parsing in my webapp, because I would have to convert the json to a real array first.
Is there a way I can write to mysql directly as a numerical array instead of json?

AFAIK, MySQL does not support array types for columns (like integer[] columns in PostgreSQL). If that is true then a JSON column is your only option. And do you have any evidence that "convert[ing] the json to a real array" incurs a significant performance penalty compared to all of the other things that your app is doing?

There are 2 solutions:
you could use the keyword dtype on to_sql:
from sqlalchemy.types import Integer
df.to_sql(dtype={"YOURCOLUMN":Integer})

docs:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html
Or you could change the dataframe to the correct type, it's better if you will use the dataframe later.
df["YOURCOLUMN"] = df["YOURCOLUMN"].astype(int)

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html
